# how do you retrieve the latest value from an oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am tryin to get the latest value from an oracle table based on server name. I have the following sql:

```
SELECT T."Node",T."Timestamp",T."MAX_User_CPU_Pct", T."MAX_System_CPU_Pct" 
FROM DW.KPX_CPU_DETAIL_HV T where T."Node"='serverA%' and T."Timestamp"=
(select max(P."Timestamp") from DW.KPX_CPU_DETAIL_HV P where P."Node"='serverA%')
```

it does not seem to be working, any ideas what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: "*does not seem to be working*" is not  valid Oracle error message.

Comment: Although it's unlikely to speed up your query, it looks to me as though `P."Node"='serverA%'` should probably be `P."Node" like 'serverA%'` - is the problem with your existing query that it returns no records?

Comment: SQL looks good. It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT T."Node",T."Timestamp",T."MAX_User_CPU_Pct", T."MAX_System_CPU_Pct" 
FROM (SELECT * FROM DW.KPX_CPU_DETAIL_HV T where T."Node" like 'serverA%' ORDER BY T."Timestamp" DESC) T
 WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

this did it for me, not sure it is the best solution but working for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, might actually be faster than the sub-select (even if it was correct):

```
SELECT T."Node",
       T."Timestamp",
       T."MAX_User_CPU_Pct", 
       T."MAX_System_CPU_Pct" 
FROM (
  SELECT p.*, 
         row_Number() over (partition by p."Node" order by p."Timestamp" desc) as rn
  FROM DW.KPX_CPU_DETAIL_HV p
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Comment: this is also taking a very long time to complete. I need it to be very fast.

Comment: @user1471980: show us the execution plan and the definition of the table including any index. Edit your question, do not post this as a comment.